# Change Groupby with Join Spark SQL query to Spark Dataframe

Tags: python

I have written my scripts initially using Spark SQL but now for performance and other reasons trying to convert the Sql queries to PySpark Dataframes.

I have `Orders` Table `(OrderID,CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,ShipperID)`
and `Shippers`  Table `(ShipperID, ShipperName)`

My Spark SQL query lists the number of orders sent by each shipper:

```
 sqlContext.sql("SELECT Shippers.ShipperName, COUNT(Orders.ShipperID) AS NumberOfOrders 
 FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID 
 GROUP BY ShipperName")
```

Now when i try to replace the above SQL query with Spark Dataframe,i write this

```
Shippers.join(Orders,["ShipperID"],'left').select(Shippers.ShipperName).groupBy(Shippers.ShipperName).agg(count(Orders.ShipperID).alias("NumberOfOrders"))
```

But I get an error here mostly because i feel aggregate count function while finding count of orderId from Orders table is wrong.

Below is the error that i get:-

```
"An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".format(target_id, ".", name), value)"
```

Can someone please help me to refactor the above SQL query to Spark Dataframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the pyspark operation for your question:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

Shippers.alias("s").join(
    Orders.alias("o"),
    on = "ShipperID",
    how = "left"
).groupby(
    "s.ShipperName"
).agg(
    F.count(F.col("o.OrderID")).alias("NumberOfOrders")
).show()
```

Comment: thanks. But I want the left join to happen from Shippers to Orders Table.Another thing in the aggregation count function can we include the Order Table to reference the OrderID.Something like this `F.count(F.col("Orders.OrderID")).alias("NumberOfOrders")`.I am asking this because in my actual problem that column on which i want to perform count operations exist in both the tables which I am trying to join.

Comment: sure adding the achanges in a minute

Comment: Thanks i have edited the original question based on my previous comment

Comment: is the new solution helpful to you

Comment: I get the same error 
`/opt/mapr/spark/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:`

Comment: Share your function or whole code snippet the error is something else

Comment: The issue is again with the aggregation column line.If i run like this `F.count(F.col("OrderID")).alias("NumberOfOrders")` this works

Comment: Share the whole error message and if possible full code snippet as well